# SendGrid inbound parse nordic chars

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks, sendgrid

Completely stuck on a problem related to the inbound parse webhook functionality offered by SendGrid: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook/

First off everything is working just fine with retrieving the mail sent to my application endpoint. Using `Request.Form` I'm able to retrieve the data and work with it.

The problem is that we started noticing question mark symbols instead of letters when recieving some mails (written in swedish using Å Ä and Ö). This occured both when sending plaintext mails, and mails with an HTML-body.

However, this only happens every now and then. After a lot of searching I found out that if the mail is sent from e.g. Postbox or Outlook (or the like), and the application has the charset set to iso-8859-1 that's when Å Ä Ö is replaced by question marks.

To replicate the error and be able to debug it I set up a HTML page with a form using the iso-8859-1 encoding, sending a similar payload as the one seen in the link above (the default one). And after that been through testing a multitude of things trying to get it to work.

As of now I'm trying to recode the input, without success. Code I'm testing:

```
        Encoding wind1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] wind1252Bytes = wind1252.GetBytes(Request.Form.["html"]);
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1252, utf8,wind1252Bytes);
        string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

This only results in the `utf8String` producing the same result with "???" where Å Ä Ö should be. My guess here is that perhaps it's due to the Request.Form["html"] returning a UTF-16 string, of the content that is encoded already in the wrong encoding iso-8859-1.

The method for fetching the POST is as follows

```
public async Task<InboundParseModel> FetchMail(IFormCollection form)
{
        InboundParseModel _em = new InboundParseModel
        {
            To = form["to"].SingleOrDefault(),
            From = form["from"].SingleOrDefault(),
            Subject = form["subject"].SingleOrDefault(),
            Html = form["html"].SingleOrDefault(),
            Text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(form["text"].SingleOrDefault()),
            Envelope = form["envelope"].SingleOrDefault()
        };
}
```

Called from another method that the POST is done to by `FetchMail(Request.Form);`

**Project info**: ASP.NET Core 2.2, C#

So as stated earlier, I am completely stuck and don't really have any ideas on how to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Having the same problem here. If we read the content as bytes (see ReadAsByteArrayAsync()) then we get the original bytes and you can apply the encoding you want. But then you need to parse the whole content yourself, which defeats the use of SendGrid. I did not find a way to get the FormData in a specific encoding.

Comment: @MariusBancila late answer, sorry for that. I came to the same conclusion. In the end we decided to switch to MailGun instead that also overall (in the testing we've done) had a better parser overall and more settings for our needs.